# R combination subset

Tags: r, combinations

I have data as below. I would like to get all subsets of 2 and 5 elements (order of elements not important).

In below case as there are 8 elements - total 28 combinations of 2 elements and 56 combinations of 5 elements are possible. How could I get list of elements in each subset?

```
element_list =c(0,1,3,4,2,2,7,4)
```

Comment: Is there anything that you have already tried? Also: I'm not sure if I understand correctly, but it might help to search for *"Permutation"*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use `combn`, iterating over the `m` value which we choose to be 2 and 5

```
combos <- lapply(c(2, 5), combn, x = element_list, simplify = FALSE)
lengths(combos)
# [1] 28 56
```

Or drop the `simplify` argument to return a list of matrices.

Comment: I tried  `com=as.data.frame(combos[[2]])` to save combinations of 5 elements. But each combination is saved as a column. Any simpler way to save each combination in a row?

Comment: Maybe something like `do.call(rbind, lapply(combs[[2]], function(x) setNames(as.data.frame.list(x), 1:5)))` if you're using `combos`.  Otherwise just `as.data.frame(t(combos[[2]]))`

Comment: Actually it's just `as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, combos[[2]]))` if you use `simplify = FALSE`